# Flutter PopupMenu change icon color

Tags: colors, dart, flutter, popup, icons

how to change icon colour on PopupMenuButton, I have used Theme with iconTheme but it doesn't affect the icon on CheckedPopupMenuItem nor PopupMenuItem.

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        actions: <Widget>[
          Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              cardColor: Colors.indigo,
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            child: ListTileTheme(
              iconColor: Colors.white,
              child: PopupMenuButton<String>(
                onSelected: _showCheckedMenuSelections,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
                  CheckedPopupMenuItem<String>(
                    value: _checkedValue1,
                    checked: _showRoles,
                    child: Text(_checkedValue1, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1),
                  ),
                  const PopupMenuDivider(),
                  PopupMenuItem<String>(
                    value: 'Get Link',
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.phonelink),
                      title: Text('Get link', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

The result is look like this :
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just do this

```
 appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white, size: 10.0),
          elevation: 4.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the `Icon` widget inside `IconButton` which provides `color` property to change the icon color. Sample code below:

```
value: 'Get Link',
    child: ListTile(
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.phonelink,
      color: Colors.blue,),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    title: Text('Get link', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1),
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: yes, i am using it on PopupMenuItem, but the CheckedPopupMenu's icon can't be changes.

Comment: it is just a string and bool value, you can refer [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CheckedPopupMenuItem-class.html)